# Algorithm to generate rectangle coordinates given a set of points

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a set of points on 2D plane, each has its screen coordinates X and Y.
They are placed this way:

[image]

You see they are placed in horizontal lines, but X coordinate is quite random. A number of points in each line is not necessarily the same.

Given these coordinates, I need to generate triangles so that each edge of the triangle connects a pair of points which are close to each other, if possible:

[image]

Is there any known algorithm or library for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need [point set triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_triangulation).

In described case [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) should give desired result.

[Library by J.R.Shewchuk](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/quake/public/www/triangle.html) (and it's not hard to find triangulation implementation for any popular language)